# Firefox thinks form is not defined, but IE and Chrome do

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, xhtml

I'm trying to get the value of a drop-down menu selection. Here's my XHTML:

```
    <form action="(EmptyReference!)" method="get" name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="myValidation(this)">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
            <option value="o1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="o4">Option 4</option>
        </select>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
if (myForm.mySelect.options[myForm.mySelect.options.selectedIndex].value == 'o1')
    [...];
else if (myForm.mySelect.options[myForm.mySelect.options.selectedIndex].value == 'o2')
    [...];
else if (myForm.mySelect.options[myForm.mySelect.options.selectedIndex].value == 'o3')
    [...];
else
    [...];
```

It works perfectly in IE and Chrome. But when I press the submit button in Firefox, nothing happens. Firebug tells me myForm is not defined. What gives? Is there a workaround?

Comment: At what point is the JavaScript being called? In <body> before or after the <form> or in the <head>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getElementById()` for best compatibility.

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
if (mySelect.options[mySelect.options.selectedIndex].value == 'o1')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you should be using document.myForm

Comment: Tried that, didn't make a difference.